# Discover what is publishing on the AMQP default exchange

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

We are running a RabbitMQ server with lots of different publishers. In almost all cases they publish to specific exchanges, but we do see some traffic to the AMQP Default exchange. I would like to know which messages are published to that exchange, since it most likely is a configuration error and not-intentional.

Is there a way to bind to the default exchange, or otherwise investigate who/what is publishing on it?